# How to check has session in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to determine if an item is present in the session by has but it returns  false .

```
$session = $request->session();
 if($session->has($form->formid) ){
            return 'found';       
        }else{
            $session->put($form->formid,$link);
          
            return $session->get($form->formid);
        }
```

in the else block I set the session and it returns its value properly . But at the second time that I check session it goes into the else block again!
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the session as a variable, can you try this:

```
 if($request->session()->has($form->formid) ){
            return 'found';       
        }else{
            $request->session()->put($form->formid,$link);
          
            return $request->session()->get($form->formid);
        }
```

If you need to persist your flash data for several requests, you may use the reflash method, which will keep all of the flash data for an additional request. If you only need to keep specific flash data, you may use the keep method:

```
$request->session()->reflash(); // It flashes all
// or
$request->session()->keep([$form->formid]); // It flashes only formid
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data

Comment: I replaced my code and put reflash in else block before return. But no changes happend! @ibrahim-dogan